# Error 139 Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote the following code, but can not figure out why I am getting a segmentation fault.

EXTRA CODE:

```
// A game keeps track of a Pack, and whether it should be shuffled, the score
// and how many points it takes to win, and the Players in the game
struct Game {
  Pack pack;                    // Pack of cards
  bool shuffle;                 // Shuffle the pack after each hand
  int score[NUM_PARTNERSHIPS];  // Score for each partnership
  int points_to_win;            // Number of points to win the game
  Player players[NUM_PLAYERS];  // Players in this game, in order around   table
 };

Player* Player_to_left(int playerindex, Game *game_ptr){
    int index = (playerindex + 1)%4;
    Player *player_ptr = &(game_ptr->players[index]);
    return player_ptr;
}

static int Get_player_index(Player *player_ptr, Game *game_ptr){
    Player *one_player = &(game_ptr->players[0]);
    if(strcmp(player_ptr->name,one_player->name) == 0)
    return 0;

    Player *two_player = &(game_ptr->players[1]);
    if(strcmp(player_ptr->name,two_player->name) == 0)
    return 1;

    Player *three_player = &(game_ptr->players[2]);
    if(strcmp(player_ptr->name,three_player->name) == 0)
    return 2;

    Player *four_player = &(game_ptr->players[3]);
    if(strcmp(player_ptr->name,four_player->name) == 0)
    return 3;

    return 0;
}
```

THE MAIN PROBLEM:

```
Player* Play_trick(Game *game_ptr, int leadindex, Player *lead_ptr, Suit trump){

Card cards[4] = {Player_lead_card(lead_ptr, trump)};
Card_print(cards); cout << " led by " << lead_ptr->name << endl;

int second = (leadindex + 1)%4;
Player *two_player = Player_to_left(leadindex, game_ptr);
cards[1] = Player_lead_card(two_player, trump);
if(second >= 0 && second <= 4)
   Card_print(cards+1); cout << " led by " << two_player->name << endl;


int third = (second + 1)%4;
Player *third_player = Player_to_left(second, game_ptr);
cards[2] = Player_lead_card(third_player, trump);
if(third >= 0 && third <= 4)
    Card_print(cards+2); cout << " led by " << third_player->name << endl;

int fourth = (third + 1)%4;
Player *fourth_player = Player_to_left(third, game_ptr);
cards[3] = Player_lead_card(fourth_player, trump);
if(fourth >= 0 && fourth <=4)
Card_print(cards+3); cout << " led by " << fourth_player->name << endl;


Card *highest = cards;
int itemp = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
     if(Card_compare(cards, (cards + i), trump) < 0){
        highest = (cards + i);
        itemp = i;
     }            
  }

  if(itemp == 0){
     cout << lead_ptr->name << " takes the trick" << endl;
     return lead_ptr;
  }

  if(itemp == 1){
     cout << two_player->name << " takes the trick" << endl;
     return two_player;
  }

  if(itemp == 2){
     cout << third_player->name << " takes the trick" << endl;
     return third_player;
  }

  if(itemp == 3){
     cout << fourth_player->name << " takes the trick" << endl;
     return fourth_player;
  }
return fourth_player;
}
```

Comment: How far does it get ? You can locate the segmentation fault by printing a message like "here we are" and move it down the code until it doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: You can use a debugger and place breakpoints, then run until the breakpoint is hit.  Move the breakpoint until you figure out which line causes the issue.